# Remove element from vector while iterating over it

Tags: julia

My first try was:

```
I = Vector{String}(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])

for i in I
    if i == "fourth"
        splice!(I, 4)
    end
    print("$i\n")
end
```

Which ends up in a Bounds error:

```
BoundsError(String["first", "second", "third"], (5,))
```

Then I figured it kinda out the "handwritten" way:

```
I = Vector{String}(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])

state = start(I)

while ! done(I, state)
    (i, state) = next(I, state)

    if i == "fourth"
        splice!(I, state - 1)
        print("Delete element i=$(state - 1)\n")
        state = state - 1
        continue
    end

    print("Got: i=$i state=$state\n")
end
```

Output:

```
Got: i=first state=2
Got: i=second state=3
Got: i=third state=4
Delete element i=4
```

But yea, thats neither easy to read nor easy to write. Is there any "julian" way to delete elements from a vector, while iterating over it? Or is there any recommended data structure which explicitly supports it via some function call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but does `pop!(I)` approach what you are looking for? [Yeah, I wonder if this has something to do with spinach.]

Comment: @rickhg12hs lol, unfortunately not what I need. I need to be able to delete any element from a vector whatever position it might have while iterating over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: using `shift!` and `push!`**

```
julia> I = Vector{String}(["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]);
julia> Inew = Vector{String}(0);
julia> while !isempty(I)
         i = shift!(I);
         if i == "fourth"; println("Skipped $i"); 
         else println("Got: i = $i"); push!(Inew, i);
         end
       end
Got: i = first
Got: i = second
Got: i = third
Skipped fourth
Got: i = fifth

julia> show(Inew)
String["first", "second", "third", "fifth"]
```

---

**Solution 2: Using `splice!`**

```
julia> I = Vector{String}(["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]);
julia> i = 1;
julia> while i <= length(I)
         if I[i] == "fourth"; splice!(I,i);
         else i += 1;
         end
       end
julia> show(I)
String["first", "second", "third", "fifth"]
```

<sub>However, note that this is not necessarily more efficient, since new memory is allocated for `I` whenever you splice it *anyway* (since it's changing size).</sub>

---

**Solution 3: using `findin` and `deleteat!` (i.e. "the one-liner"):**

```
julia> I = Vector{String}(["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]);
julia> deleteat!(I, findin(I, ["second", "fourth"]))
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "first"
 "third"
 "fifth"
```

<sub>If you don't really need to perform any other intermediate actions (e.g. printing) and you just want to identify and delete elements, then this is probably the way to go.</sub>

---

**Further ramblings:**

<sub>Also, regarding your attempt to do this via a for loop: a cardinal rule when iterating with a for loop (in any language) is that the state of the variable that you're iterating over *does not change*. Disobeying this rule will usually lead to errors in the best case, or undefined behaviour and silent errors in the worst case. If the state of the variable is meant to change, then you're not looking at a 'for loop' iteration, but at the more general while loop which makes no assumption of consistent state.</sub>

<sub>I.e. what you've done here is the correct approach and you shouldn't be looking for one that involves a for loop. (and if you do happen to find one, consider that bad code and leave it alone :p ). But, yes, there were nicer-looking ways of doing it; however it's worth noting that what you did is basically re-discover the wheel, in that you made explicit the interface on which the for loop actually relies in julia. I.e. the following code:</sub>

```
for i in MyCollection; print("$i "); end
```

<sub>essentially gets internally translated as its equivalent:</sub>

```
state = start(MyCollection)
while !done( MyCollection, state)
  (i, state) = next(MyCollection, state)
  print("$i ")
end
```

---

Comment: Thanks, your second way is just what I looked for. Easy on the eyes, doesn't create a new array and simply deleting one or more elements while iterating over it. Perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `splice!` many times is very slow for large arrays:

```julia
function d!(I, s)
    i = 1
    while i <= length(I)
        if I[i] == s; splice!(I,i);
        else i += 1;
        end
    end
end

function t()
    I = rand(1:10, 1000000)
    s = 1
    d!(I,s)
    I
end

julia> @btime t()
 6.752 s (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
899975-element Array{Int64,1}:
...
```

It is better to call `deleteat!` only once with an iterator that produces all indices that should be deleted, e.g.,

```julia
function d2!(I, s)
    deleteat!(I, (i for i in eachindex(I) if I[i] == s))
end

function t2()
    I = rand(1:10, 1000000)
    s = 1
    d2!(I,s)
    I
end

julia> @btime t2()
 15.889 ms (8 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
900414-element Array{Int64,1}:
...
```